# Using lambda to provide stack-based context (eg. path for file manipulation)

Tags: lambda, java-8

I've though of a subtle way (which might have already be implemented and discussed) to do the equivalent of this in Groovy (taken from the [Groovy documentation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565020/is-java-lambda-expression-is-similar-logic-of-groovy-closure#comment39927502_25567047)) and I am trying to improve it, if that is possible:

```
ant.sequential {
    echo("inside sequential")
    def myDir = "target/AntTest/"
    mkdir(dir: myDir)
    copy(todir: myDir) {
        fileset(dir: "src/test") {
            include(name: "**/*.groovy")
        }
    }
    echo("done")
}
```

This example is fine, but I'm not doing an Ant based program: I want to do some fluent API to manipulate files and directories (let's call it *FileManipulator*, and I'm bad with names :)).

Basically this would be that:

```
new DefaultFileManipulator(Paths.get("root")).with(() -> {
  newFile("file1");          // create file      root/file1
  newFile("file2");          // create file      root/file2
  cd("directory1", () -> {   // create directory root/directory1
    newFile("file1");        // create file      root/directory1/file1
    cd("directory1", () -> { // create direcotry root/directory1/directory1
      newFile("file1");      // create file      root/directory1/directory1/file1
    });
    newFile("file2");        // create file      root/directory1/file2
  });
});
```

With the following interface:

```
interface FileManipulator {
  FileManipulator with(LambdaFileManipulator m);
  FileManipulator cd(String path, LambdaFileManipulator m);
  Path newFile(String path) throws IOException;
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface LambdaFileManipulator extends FileManipulator {
  void execute() throws IOException;
  default FileManipulator with(LambdaFileManipulator m) {
    return FileManipulatorStack.manipulatorFor(this).with(m);
  }
  // for each non default method of FileManipulator, the same call to FileManipulatorStack.manipulatorFor(this).
}
```

The `DefaultFileManipulator` simply implements `FileManipulator` and use the `AbstractFileManipulator` defined below.

Because I want the path to be relative, I need somehow to keep the lambda context (I don't want to mess the current working directory): I do that using a stack which is manipulated like this:

```
// visibility package, because that's technical stuff!
class FileManipulatorStack {
  private static final Map<LambdaFileManipulator , ArrayDeque<LambdaFileManipulatorDelegator>> stacks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  static LambdaFileManipulatorDelegator manipulatorFor(final LambdaFileManipulator delegatee) {
    final ArrayDeque<LambdaFileManipulatorDelegator> stack = stacks.get(delegatee);
    if (null == stack) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("state is empty for [" + delegatee + "]");
    }
    return stack.getLast();
  }

  static void delegate(final Path scopedPath, final LambdaFileManipulator delegatee) {
    final LambdaFileManipulatorDelegator handler = new LambdaFileManipulatorDelegator(scopedPath);
    final ArrayDeque<LambdaFileManipulatorDelegator> stack = stacks.computeIfAbsent(delegatee, key -> new ArrayDeque<>());
    stack.addLast(handler);
    try {
      delegatee.execute();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      throw new DelegatedFileCreatorHandlerUndeclaredException(e);
    } finally {
      final LambdaFileManipulatorDelegator ss = stack.removeLast();
      if (ss != handler) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("invalid stack");
      }
      if (stack.isEmpty()) {
        stacks.remove(delegatee);
      }
    }
  }

  static class LambdaFileManipulatorDelegator extends AbstractFileManipulator {
     ... constructor ... 
  }
}

abstract class AbstractFileManipulator implements FileManipulator {
  private final Path root;
  public AbstractFileManipulator(Path root) {
    this.root = requireNonNull(root, "root");
  }

  public final FileManipulator with(LambdaFileManipulator m) {
    FileManipulatorStack.delegate(root, m);
    return this;
  }

  public final FileManipulator cd(String path, LambdaFileManipulator m) {
    FileManipulatorStack.delegate(root.resolve(path), m);
    return this;  
  }

  public final Path newFile(String path) {
    Path p = root.resolve(path);
    Files.createFile(p);
    return p;
  }
}
```

My question might not be "good" in regard to Stackoverflow rules, but here is:

**How can I improve this without adding the `FileManipulator` as parameter to lambda (I would have use `Consumer` for that instead)?**

Is there problem by using the lambda as key to a map? (in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565020/is-java-lambda-expression-is-similar-logic-of-groovy-closure#comment39927502_25567047), it says the lambda will be dynamically converted to an instance of `LambdaFileManipulator`, then I perhaps don't need a map of stack).

Did I miss some feature of Java 8 that would allow me to make a lambda an implementation method of some class?

**Edit:** I answered my own question ... and this can't work because the lambda does not/never know it is an implementation of `FileManipulator`. So, it can not call those methods. It might work using static methods (and some context), but I think it is worse than having a parameter.

Comment: Right, lambda expressions won’t inherit anything from the functional interface they will eventually implement. That’s in line with the fact that `this` and `super` within a lambda expression do not refer to the lambda instance but its surrounding context. Further, these instances have an unspecified identity and are therefore inappropriate for being used as keys in a map. If your manipulators run sequentially, you may store context information in a `static ThreadLocal` behind the scenes, otherwise, a parameter is unavoidable.

Comment: I added a `parameter`, since even with a context, that won't allow me to avoid prefixing my calls by `parameter.`: there are no gains in maintaining a context when I require a `parameter` with its own context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having compilation issues leading to me thinking my idea would work:

- The lambda is only casted when needed, eg: it produce an implementation of that interface using lambda as implementation site of the single abstract method.
- Turns out that neither Javac, neither Eclipse accepted calling `newFile`, `cd` out of context. If fails with *The method `newFile(String)` is undefined for the type `FileManipulatorTest`*.

Thus, I will inject the `FileManipulator` as parameter (which I was trying to avoid).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how it could possibly look like the example shown where newfile() and cd() are called without an object in front of them.

They are not static functions and there is no reason for the enclosing class to have implemented these.

I came up with this that doesn't use lambdas but can run something pretty close to your example.

```
enum FileActionType {
    CD, NEWFIlE;
}

class FileAction {

    final public String name;
    final public FileActionType type;
    final public FileAction actions[];

    public FileAction(String name, FileActionType type, FileAction[] actions) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.actions = actions;
    }
}
```

Implement static functions:

```
public static void execute(File f, FileAction... actions) {
    f.mkdirs();
    for (int i = 0; i < actions.length; i++) {
        FileAction action = actions[i];
        switch (action.type) {
            case CD:
                execute(new File(f, action.name), action.actions);
                break;

            case NEWFIlE:
                try {
                    Files.createFile(new File(f, action.name).toPath());
                } catch (IOException ex) {

                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

public static FileAction cd(String name, FileAction... actions) {
    return new FileAction(name, FileActionType.CD, actions);
}

public static FileAction newFile(String name) {
    return new FileAction(name, FileActionType.NEWFIlE, null);
}
```

Use like this:

```
execute(
        new File("/tmp/test"),
        newFile("file1"), // create file      root/file1
        newFile("file2"), // create file      root/file2
        cd(
                "directory1",
                newFile("file1"), // create file      root/directory1/file1
                cd("directory1", // create direcotry root/directory1/directory1
                        newFile("file1") // create file      root/directory1/directory1/file1
                ),
                newFile("file2") // create file      root/directory1/file2
        )
);
```

Comment: That's exactly where the magic is: the `LambdaFileManipulator` interface extends `FileManipulator` with one extra, non default, method (`execute`). The other method are default'ed to get a companion object of the lambda. So; the compiler sees them because the lambda implements an interface.

Comment: Sorry I missed the default methods for cd() and newfile() as they are only mentioned in a comment.  I am still not sure what the advantage of the lambda approach here has over just passing ordinary objects. The need for a static variable bothers me although I suppose it works.